# How to push object from oner array to another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays now once i rendered the data from backend i want to push just object from array2 to array1 not the array itself.

How can i just push object from array2 to array1 I dont want to push as array.

```
ctrl.js

var array1 = [{name:'john', address:'cliffwood ave'}]

var array2 = [{name:'Mike', address:'florence ave'}]

array1.push(array2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to push a single object in the array, you could just reference it by it's specific index :

```
array1.push(array2[0]);
```

Otherwise, if you wanted to push all of the items, you might consider just concatenating them via the [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function :

```
array1.concat(array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mutate `array1`:

```
array1.push.apply(array1, array2);
```

Otherwise:

```
var array3 = array1.concat(array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ES6 you can use the [`spread` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
array1.push(...array2);
```

which is functionally equivalent to this ES5 method...

```
 array1.push.apply(array1, array2);
```

...mentioned in one of the other answers.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/L7rpf7qe/)

Answer (score 0):

To push `{name:'Mike', address:'florence ave'}` into array1 :

```
array1.push(array2[0]);
```

As the object you want is simply the first element in your array2 variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
(var I = 0; I <= array2.length-1 ; I++){
  array1.push(array2[I])
}
```